# Unable to create node lables for nodepools in azure AKS

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I want to create labels for each node under a nodepool , but i dont find this option in azure cli , can someone help me with this?

Expected : 
Must be able to label nodepools which can help in autoscaling and pod scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding labels is a feature that is still in progress (tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1088).

However, you can add Taints using ARM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/agentpools/createorupdate#examples or Terraform: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html#node_taints (looks like the CLI still lacks the functionality).

Comment: Thank you . Can you help me with how to enable vmss while creating a cluster? I have done the registration but when i try to add the flag --enable-vmss an error is thrown : az: error: unrecognized arguments: --enable-vmss --enable-vmss

Comment: You probably need to upgrade the azure cli and install the aks-preview (or update it with `az extension update -n aks-preview`